# Is the algebraic closure of a $p$-adic field complete

Tags: general-topology, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a finite extension of $\mathbf{Q}_p$, i.e., a $p$-adic field. (Is this standard terminology?)

Why is (or why isn't) an algebraic closure $\overline{K}$ complete?

Maybe this holds more generally:

Let $K$ be a complete Hausdorff discrete valuation field. Then, why is $\overline{K}$ complete?

I think I can show that finite extensions of complete discrete valuation fields are complete.

Comment: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{1/n} p^n$ converges but it is not in $\overline{\mathbf{Q}_p}$, it is in only in $\mathbf{C}_p$.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The algebraic closure has countably infinite dimension over $\mathbb Q_p$, and therefore (by the Baire category theorem) is not metrically complete.  (Except the case $\mathbb Q_\infty = \mathbb R$, where the algebraic closure has finite dimension, and is metrically complete.)

**explanation**

In $\mathbb Q_p$, let $x_n$ be a solution of $X^{n}=p$.  Then $\{x_2,x_3,x_4,\dots\}$ is linearly independent over $\mathbb Q_p$.
But we still need a proof that the algebraic closure does not have uncountable dimension.

Torsten Schoenberg provided the missing part:
Countable dimension follows from Krasner / Hensel and compactness of $\mathbb Z_p$ which shows for each $d \in \mathbb N$
, $\mathbb Q_p$
only has only countably many (actually finitely many) extension of degree $d$ in $\overline{\mathbb Q_p}$. I doubt there is a more elementary argument for that.

**former explanation**
We see in [Incompleteness of algebraic closure of p-adic number field, from $9$ years ago question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4274011/442) that it is incorrect...

How about an example?  In $\mathbb Q_2$, the partial sums of the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{n+1/n}
$$
belong to $\overline{\mathbb Q_2}$, but the sum of the series does not.  The partial sums form a Cauchy sequence with no limit in $\overline{\mathbb Q_2}$.

Why does this sum not exist in $\overline{\mathbb Q_2}$ ?

It is not trivial, but interesting: any $x$ which is algebraic of degree $n$ over $\mathbb Q_2$ has a unique series expansion
$$
x = \sum 2^{u_j}
$$
where $u_j \to \infty$ (unless it is a finite sum) and all $u_j$ are rationals with denominator that divides $n!$.  (Maybe divides $n$ in fact?)  But the series expansion in this example has arbitrarily large denominators.

Comment: Is there any straight-forward example of a Cauchy sequence that does not converge?

Comment: I am astounded that GEdgar was able to answer fretty's request for an example 50 seconds before the request was posted. Surely that ought to be worth at least 1,000 points.

Comment: Could you tell me the reason why the denominator of $j_j$ devides $n!$?

Comment: One can avoid the use of countable dimension by applying Baire directly to the countable family of subsets $H_n := \{x \in \overline{\mathbb Q_p} : [\mathbb Q_p(x) : \mathbb Q_p] \le n \}$ whose union clearly is $\overline{\mathbb Q_p}$ and which are easily shown to be closed, but none of which can contain an open subset of $\overline{\mathbb Q_p}$ (because otherwise one could easily show it would contain all of $\overline{\mathbb Q_p}$). This is how it is proved in Schikhof's *Ultrametric Calculus*, Theorem 16.6.

Comment: Alternatively, countable dimension follows from Krasner / Hensel and compactness of $\mathbb Z_p$ which shows for each $d \in \mathbb N$, $\mathbb Q_p$ only has only countably many (actually finitely many) extension of degree $d$ in $\overline{\mathbb Q_p}$. I doubt there is a more elementary argument for that.

Answer (score 17):

Small addition: One might try to repeat this process of algebraic closure / analytic completion. Kürschak proved that this process terminates after one more step, i.e. 
the completion of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ is algebraically closed.

More generally, if you start with a non-archimedean valued field $K$ and denote $\overline{K}$ the algebraic closure and $\widetilde{K}$ the analytic completion, then $\widetilde{\overline{\widetilde{K}}}$ is algebraically closed.

Comment: This result is not due to Teichmüller, but to Kürschak (1913). See page 5 of www.rzuser.uni-heidelberg.de/~ci3/hist_val.pdf.

Comment: @KCd: That's interesting, I think the professor who taught me this explicitly mentioned Teichmüller at the time, but perhaps it was a related result to this. Anyway, I corrected my answer.