# Fields that are both algebraically closed and complete with respect to a metric

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, field-theory

The statement is basically in the question. I know that $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed and a complete metric space, which makes it a very interesting field. I was wondering if there were other fields which are algebraically closed and complete with respect to a metric. For instance, can this happen in characteristic $p$?

Comment: [Another example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/123962/553213)

Comment: thanks, do you know if this can happen in characteristic p?