# any $x$ which is algebraic of degree $n$ over $\mathbb Q_2$ has a unique series expansion $ x = \sum 2^{u_j} $

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

any $x$ which is algebraic of degree $n$ over $\mathbb Q_2$ has a unique series expansion
$$
x = \sum 2^{u_j}
$$
where $u_j \to \infty$ (unless it is a finite sum)

Then, I would like to prove all rational numbers $u_j$ are rationals **with denominator that divides $n!$**.

$x$ is root of n-dimmensional polynomial over $\mathbb Q_2$, so $a_nx^n＋a_{n-1}x^{n-1}＋・・・＋a_1x＋a_0＝0$. I tried to see order 2 on both side, but in vain, and I cannot proceed from here.
Thank you in advance.

**P.S
This statement is from [Is the algebraic closure of a $p$-adic field complete](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123925/is-the-algebraic-closure-of-a-p-adic-field-complete?noredirect=1&lq=1)
's GEdgar's answer. Could you give explanation why denominator  decides $n!$?**

Comment: I have some doubts - you're suggesting that any degree $n$ extension of $\mathbb Q_2$ is contained in $\mathbb Q_2(2^{1/n!})$; but $\mathbb Q_2(2^{1/n!})$ is totally ramified over $\mathbb Q_2$, so it will not contain unramified extensions. And it doesn't matter whether you use $n!$ or some bigger integer. But I may be missing something - where does this problem come from?

Comment: If, as I assume, $u_j$ is supposed to be a sequence of elements of $\mathbb Q$, then it is not even clear to me how e.g. $2^{1/k}$ is defined in order to make something unique to begin with. After all, there might be $k$ different $k$-th roots of $2$ in our field.